# Странность с указателями в Си

Tags: c, указатели

Я хочу узнать, почему вот эта программа работает без ошибки сегментации:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *month_name(int);

main()
{
    char *month[15];
    for(int i = 1, j = 0; month_name(i) != "No month"; i++, j++)
    {
        month[j] = month_name(i);
        while(*month[j])
        {
            printf("%c", *month[j]++);

            if(!*month[j])
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

char *month_name(int num)
{
    static char *name[] = {
        "No month", "January", "February", 
        "Mart", "April", "May", "June", 
        "July", "August", "September", "October", 
        "November", "December"
    };
    return (num < 1 || num > 12) ? name[0] : name[num];
}
```

А эта с ошибкой сегментации и выводом непонятных символов на экран:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *month_name(int);

main()
{
    char *month[15];
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 1, j = 0; month_name(i) != "No month"; i++, j++)
    {
        month[j] = month_name(i);
    }

        !!!!!
        while(*month[k])
        {
            printf("%c", *month[k]++);

            if(!*month[k])
            {
                printf("\n");
                k++;
            }
        }
        !!!!!

}

char *month_name(int num)
{
    static char *name[] = {
        "No month", "January", "February", 
        "Mart", "April", "May", "June", 
        "July", "August", "September", "October", 
        "November", "December"
    };
    return (num < 1 || num > 12) ? name[0] : name[num];
}
```

Comment: Вы всё правильно написали? Меня смущает, что в первом варианте `while` внутри `for`, а во втором варианте нет. И еще, не сравнивайте строки C-style операцией `==`, для этого есть функция `strcmp`

Comment: Во втором случае, после `for` надо инициализировать `month[12] = "";`, сейчас там грязь, по которой и вылетаете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так

```
month_name(i) != "No month"
```

писать в общем случае нельзя. Если у вас отрабатывает верно - то только из-за оптимизации, которая одинаковые строки только для чтения объединяет. Стоит скомпилировать в VC++ код с ключиком `/GF-`, как все тут же перестанет работать...

Во втором случае вы просто идете по массиву указателей (из-за `k++`) и выскакиваете за декабрь к следующему указателю - а он содержит какой-то мусор, который указывает на другой мусор, каковой и пытается не то вывестись, не то привести к аварийному завершению.

Вот если вы напишете

```
char *month[15] = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
```

то все сработает :)

Comment: То есть, я правильно понял, что когда создаёшь массив указателей `char *month[15];` , все эти 15 штук указывают в пустоту?

Comment: Если это локальный массив (как у вас), то он просто заполнен мусором. Грубая модель - есть кусок памяти, в котором что-то там валялось, память не была вытерта (записана нулями или еще чем), а теперь объявлено - здесь будут лежать мои 15 указателей. И все. Их значения остались от невытертой памяти, и могут указывать вообще фиг куда. Но даже если б память была записана NULL-укаателями - легче бы не стало, потому что у вас бы было разыменование NULL, что ничуть не легче...